# string to datetime conversion in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

the below line is giving me 'FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION' in salesforce . please provide me the alternative for this .

imr.Assigned_DTM__c = DateTime.valueOfGmt(('06/08/2013 06:30:22').replaceAll('/','-'));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issues is that you use incorrect format

```apex
System.debug(DateTime.valueOfGmt(('06/08/2013 06:30:22').replaceAll('/','-')));

System.debug(DateTime.valueOfGmt(('2013/08/06 06:30:22').replaceAll('/','-')));
```

console output:

```
08:19:40:061 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|0012-02-03 06:30:22
08:19:40:061 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|2013-08-06 06:30:22
```

as you can see from the debug, the first variant returns incorrect datetime value.

[Official documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) says the following

> **valueOfGmt** Returns a Datetime that contains the
>   value of the specified String. The String should use the standard date
>   format **“yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss”** in the GMT time zone

correct your initial string with datetime.

**UPDATE**

```apex
String myDate = '06/08/2013 06:30:22';
String stringDate = myDate.substring(6,10) + '-' + 
                    myDate.substring(3,5) + '-' +
                    myDate.substring(0,2) + ' ' +
                    myDate.substring(11,19);
DateTime dt = datetime.valueOf(stringDate);
System.debug(String.valueOfGmt(dt));
```

log:
`dt|"2013-08-06T03:30:22.000Z"`

Comment: yes , but the problem is I'll not get the string in “yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss” format . so is there any way I can convert string in "mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss" format in to datetime ?

Comment: try DateTime.format(string) as documented in https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_2

Comment: @RajkishorSahu _link seems to be outdated_.